# Flutter: How to stop timer after N seconds interval?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-timer

I am using below code to start the timer

Timer Snippet:

```
 _increamentCounter() {
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 2), (timer) {
       setState(() {
         _counter++;
       });
    });
  }


 RaisedButton raisedButton =
        new RaisedButton(child: new Text("Button"), onPressed: () {
            _increamentCounter();
        });
```

What I all want is to stop this timer after specific(N) timer interval.

Comment: Your question title says that you want to *stop* the `Timer`, but later you say that you want to *start* the `Timer`.  Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to cancel the `Timer` after a specific number of *intervals* and not after a specific *time*, perhaps this solution is more appropriate than the other answers?

```
Timer _incrementCounterTimer;


_incrementCounter() {
    _incrementCounterTimer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 2), (timer) {     
        counter++; 

        if( counter == 5 ) // <-- Change this to your preferred value of N
            _incrementCounterTimer.cancel();

        setState(() {});
    });
}


 RaisedButton raisedButton = new RaisedButton(
    child: new Text("Button"), 
    onPressed: () { _incrementCounter(); }
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Future.delayed.

```
Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: n), () => _increamentCounter());
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to `Future.delayed()`, you can also use

```dart
Timer(const Duration(seconds: n), () => _increamentCounter());
```

The `Timer` class exposes a couple extra methods like `.cancel()`, `.tick`, and `isActive`, so prefer it if you see yourself needing them down the road.